# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " /09"

Tags: java

```
int ay = Integer.parseInt(tarih.substring(tarih.indexOf("/"),tarih.lastIndexOf("/")));
```

The error I get is :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/09"

`09` is an input from the user.

How can I solve this error without using try catch?

Comment: The error states it clearly .. `/09` is not in a number format.

Comment: You would be better by using a `Scanner` on your `String` with `/` as delimiter.

Comment: Are you parsing a date by any chance?

Comment: Use splitString function.

Comment: Why use scanner instead of splitString?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one too many characters from the substring going to `parseInt`.  The start index needs to be increased by one.  Change

```
int ay = Integer.parseInt(tarih.substring(tarih.indexOf("/"),tarih.lastIndexOf("/")));
```

to

```
int ay = Integer.parseInt(tarih.substring(tarih.indexOf("/") + 1,tarih.lastIndexOf("/")));
```

This is because the starting index is inclusive in the [`substring` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-).

> **Parameters**:
>
> beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive.
>
> endIndex - the ending index, exclusive.

Then you will get `"09"` as the substring, which can be parsed by `Integer.parseInt`.

Answer (score 2):

`/09` cannot be parsed as an integer, since it has a character which is not a digit - `/`.

You should lose the leading slash :

```
int ay = Integer.parseInt(tarih.substring(tarih.indexOf("/")+1,tarih.lastIndexOf("/")));
```